# Function to check in a binary tree is balanced C++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a function that uses recursion to check if a binary search tree is balanced.

The template for the function I am using is

```
template<class T>
int BST<T>::is_balanced(BSTNode<T> *p) const
{

    if (p == 0) // Base case
        return 0;
    else {

}
}
```

Ive also created a function that checks the number of leaf nodes in the tree

```
template<class T>
int BST<T>::number_of_leaves(BSTNode<T>* start) const 
{
    if(start == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(start->right == NULL && start->left==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return number_of_leaves(start->right) + number_of_leaves(start-> left);
}
```

From what I've read and saw, there needs to be something that gets the height of the left and right nodes. Is the second function able to be used for that purpose or am I overlooking something.

Any help to get this solved would be appreciated as all my attempts have not worked.

if needed this is the BSTNODE class

```
template<class T>
class BSTNode {
public:
    BSTNode() { left = right = 0; }
    BSTNode(const T& e, BSTNode<T> *l = 0, BSTNode<T> *r = 0) 
        { el = e, left = l, right = r; }
    T el;
    BSTNode<T> *left, *right;
};
```

Comment: is this helps? - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/

Comment: It seems like your code is trying to solve a different problem. What does the number of leaves matter here? Try getting the height of the tree and checking that the absolute difference between the heights of each node's subtree is less than 1.

Comment: I've tried using the geeksforgeeks method, but for my tests it just says all tree's are balanced, I'll add the example to the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Ended up working it out. I had confused myself by thinking I needed another function for the height. Below is the code i used

```
template<class T>
int BST<T>::is_balanced(BSTNode<T>* root) const
{
        if(root == NULL)
        return 0;
        else {
                int lh = is_balanced(root->left);
                int rh= is_balanced(root->right);
                if (lh == -1 || rh == -1) return -1;
        if (abs(lh-rh) > 1) return -1;
        if(lh > rh) return lh +1;
        return rh+1;
        }
}
```